# Is there a way to write a file and skip the autocmd on write?

Tags: autocmd, save, lsp

My `.vimrc` has,

```
autocmd FileType rust autocmd  BufWritePre <buffer> call LanguageClient#textDocument_formatting_sync()
```

This works great, unless my LanguageClient crashes. Then I can't write the buffer. Is there an easy method to write a file and skip the autocmd, you'd think `:w!` but alas, even that is blocked by autocmd

Comment: PS instead of Filetype autocommands, consider ftplugins

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generally speaking, that's exactly what the [`:noautocmd`](https://vimhelp.org/autocmd.txt.html#:noautocmd) *command modifier* is for. Just prefix your command with that and all autocommands should be disabled for just the run of that command.

```
:noautocmd w
```

Of course, this is the scorched earth approach. If there are other autocommands that you need to keep enabled and you're trying to ignore just the one you mentioned than a different approach is required. If this is the case I'd suggest explicitly mentioning it in your question, though there are few things I can mention right now...

First, want to see which, if any, autocommands are being run? Try this:

```
:9verbose w
```

Speaking for myself, I have two plugins that have actions that are triggered by an autocommand associated with `:w`. They aren't what I'd call critical but I may still want to keep them intact. They are *not* associated with `BufWritePre`, though, so *for me* an alternative to `:noautocmd` would be to disable just the `BufWritePre` event, do the write, then re-enable that event:

```
:set eventignore+=BufWritePre | w | set eventignore-=BufWritePre
```

That could easily be wrapped up in a mapping or user command.

Answer (score 2):

Just ignore all errors from `LanguageClient`

```
silent! call LanguageClient#textDocument_formatting_sync()
```

Note: the last error message is still available as `echo v:errmsg`.